# Array of validation rules in sometimes() conditional validation

Tags: php, laravel

Something like this:

```
    //I know, this type of implementation does not exist in Laravel,
    // but I want something like this
    $validator->sometimes([
        'form.id' => 'required|integer',
        'form.date' => 'required|date',
        'form.name' => 'required|string|max:255'
    ], function($input) use ($age){
        return $age > 18;
    })->validate();
```

Same conditional for an array of validation rules. Is there any way to do it? Or I need to do individually? like the example below.

```
    $validator->sometimes('form.id', 'required|integer', function($input) use ($age){
        return $age > 18;
    })
    ->sometimes('form.date', 'required|date', function($input) use ($age){
        return $age > 18;
    })
    ->sometimes('form.name', 'required|string|max:255', function($input) use ($age){
        return $age > 18;
    })
    ->validate();
```

Comment: Wouldn't just having a conditional check around the validation achieve the same thing? e.g. `if ($age > 18) { ... do validation ... } else { ... no validation ... }`.

Comment: why dont u use `required_if` ?